# What is this variant of remember doing?

Tags: archaic-language, licensing

I **remember to have heard** that your mother has many suitors

[Source](http://classics.mit.edu/Homer/odyssey.3.iii.html)

> "My friend," said Nestor, "now that you remind me, I **remember to have heard** that your mother has many suitors, who are ill disposed towards you and are making havoc of your estate. Do you submit to this tamely, or are public feeling and the voice of heaven against you? Who knows but what Ulysses may come back after all, and pay these scoundrels in full, either single-handed or with a force of Achaeans behind him? If Minerva were to take as great a liking to you as she did to Ulysses when we were fighting before Troy (for I never yet saw the gods so openly fond of any one as Minerva then was of your father), if she would take as good care of you as she did of him, these wooers would soon some of them him, forget their wooing."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usage, with *remember* in the sense of "recall, experience a memory" taking  an infinitive complement (Direct Object) is now obsolete. Today we would employ a gerund or *that* complement:

> I remember hearing that ...
>   I remember I have heard that ...

Nowadays infinitive complements with *remember* are reserved for situations where *remember* has the sense "recall and perform (an obligation)" ...

> Did you remember to wash the dishes?

See [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/26348/32) for more about the present-day distinction between *remember to VERB* and *remember VERBing*.