# Gerund, how to identify it clearly?

Tags: word-choice, gerunds

I'm looking for my notebook. I remember ..... it into my suitcase when I left for work.

Q: Do I always have to fill 'gerund' in the blank?

Answer (score 1):

Each English verb *licenses* (permits) a particular set of complement types. *Remember* is slightly unusual in having a different meaning with different complement types.

- With gerund clauses and fused relative clauses, *remember* has the sense “recall, experience a memory of” a previous event:

  > I remember **putting** my noteboook into my briefcase when I left for work.
  >   I remember **where I put** my notebook when I left for work—in my briefcase.
- With infinitive clauses, however, it means “recall (and subsequently perform)” a future obligation:

  > I remembered **to put** my noteboook into my briefcase when I left for work.
  >   Remember **to put** your noteboook into your briefcase when you leave for work.
- With ‘content’ clauses it may have either meaning; the relationship between the tenses in the main clause and the subordinate clause tell you which is intended.

  > I remember **[that] I put** my notebook into my briefcase when I left for work.
  >   I remembered **[that] I must put** my notebook into my briefcase when I left for work.

  <sub>As [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/27114/32) tells us, you may encounter infinitive phrases being employed in this double sense as recently as the late nineteenth century; but this is no longer the case in Present-day English.</sub>