# Which one is right of the following two sentence?

Tags: tense, questions, do-support

> Do you remember something?
>
> Did you remember something?

Which one is correct and idiomatic?

Comment: Without context? Not answerable. Please see our [meta post on details](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [to+infinitive or -ing](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26348/toinfinitive-or-ing)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context in which it's used. Both can be said to be correct.

For example,

1) police is investigating a theft and crime scene and ask the question to the person beaten by the thieves - "Do you remember something that happened that night?"

2) "Did you remember to pay the electricity bill?".

Difference made by the context:

When we use "Do you remember...", there is an implicit curiosity to know about the thing.

When we use "Did you remember...", we are interested in the consequences of the thing happened in the past.